# Is there a way to run python scripts on an amd gpu without pyopencl

Tags: python

I have been trying to read a csv dataset with python for a while now. However the file is very large (14.6 MB) and it has 1.7 million cells. Because of this it takes a lot of time for pandas to read it. I was wondering if I could run python on the gpu to speed it up. If yes, then is PyOpenCl  the only way to run it on an AMD radeon r5 graphics card? I am fairly new to programming.

Comment: CSV is a stream format, and parsing it is mostly I/O limited. Since a GPU works best for *parallel* tasks (streams are *sequential*) and incur a heavy cost for moving data in/out, it seems highly unsuitable for CSV. Either way, 14.6 MB / 2 million entries isn't all that much – how long *does* pandas take to parse it?

Comment: 14MB is a pretty small file in the grand scheme of things.

You might want to post up the code you are using to read it - as its likely there is a gross inefficiency somewhere.